# space between part title and chapter title in toc [Koma]

Tags: table-of-contents, koma-script

Is there a way to decrease the vertical space between part title and chapter titles and also decrease the space between chapters and the following part?
I looked for a solution but most people seem to use some special `toc`-packages
are those packages necessary or is it possible to do this just with `koma-script`?

```
\documentclass[
final,
paper=a4,
listof=totoc,
captions=tableheading,
listof=totoc,
numbers=noenddot,
headings=big,
chapterprefix=false]
{scrreprt}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \listoffigures
    \listoftables
    \cleardoubleoddpage 
    \part{Stuff}
    \blinddocument  
    \part{More Stuff}
    \blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

**Update**
My aim is to emulate the `classicthesis`-toc style, therefore I added some more space between the `listoftable`, figures listings and the bibliography in the header-file to esdd's solution (by adding `\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\vspace{.25\baselineskip}}`). Is there a more elegant way to achieve the same result?

```
    \documentclass[
final,
fontsize=12pt,              
open=right,     
twoside = true,
paper=a4,
listof=totoc,
captions=tableheading,
listof=totoc,
numbers=noenddot,
headings=big,
DIV=calc,
BCOR=8.72mm,
chapterprefix=false
]
{scrreprt}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{xcolor}% <- load this package before tocstyle
\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage{ebgaramond}
\usepackage{microtype}
%\usepackage[fullfamily,opticals,minionint,footnotefigures]{MinionPro} 
\recalctypearea
\definecolor{red}{RGB}{192,0,0}
\definecolor{halfgray}{gray}{0.55} 

\setkomafont{disposition}{\rmfamily}
\addtokomafont{chapter}{\normalsize\scshape}
\addtokomafont{section}{\normalsize\scshape}
\addtokomafont{subsection}{\normalsize\itshape}     
\setkomafont{chapterentrypagenumber}{\normalfont}
\setkomafont{chapterentry}{\mdseries\scshape\lowercase}
\setkomafont{chapterentrypagenumber}{\normalfont}
\setkomafont{part}{\large\color{red}\scshape\MakeUppercase} 

\renewcommand*{\partpagestyle}{empty}
\setkomafont{part}{\large\color{red}\scshape\MakeUppercase} 
\setkomafont{partnumber}{\large}
\setkomafont{partentry}{\color{red}}
\renewcommand\addparttocentry[2]{%
    \addtocentrydefault{part}{\protect\large\textsc{\lowercase{#1}}}{%
        \protect\texorpdfstring{\large\scshape\lowercase{#2}}{#2}}}
\setkomafont{partentrypagenumber}{\normalfont\color{red}}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[tocnumwidth=1.3em,innerskip=2mm]{part} 

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{xpatch} 
\xapptocmd\appendix{% 
    \addtocontents{toc}{\value{tocdepth}=0}% 
}{}{}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{textcase}
\usepackage{fontaxes}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{bm}

\DeclareMathAlphabet\EuRoman{U}{eur}{m}{n}
\SetMathAlphabet\EuRoman{bold}{U}{eur}{b}{n}
\newcommand{\eurom}{\EuRoman}

\makeatletter
\newsavebox{\feline@chapter}
\newcommand\feline@chapter@marker[1][4cm]{%
    \sbox\feline@chapter{%
        \resizebox{!}{#1}{\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}%
            \colorbox{white}{\color{halfgray}$\bm{\eurom\thechapter}$}}}%!!!!!Error?
    \raisebox{\depth}{\usebox{\feline@chapter}}%
}
\renewcommand\chapterformat{\sbox\feline@chapter{\feline@chapter@marker[1.61cm]}%
    \makebox[0pt][l]{\hspace*{\marginparsep}\usebox\feline@chapter}}

\renewcommand\chapterlinesformat[3]{%
    \parbox[t]{\textwidth}{\raggedchapter\MakeUppercase{#3}}%
    #2%
    \\\rule{\textwidth}{.4pt}
}

\renewcommand*{\sectionlinesformat}[4]{%
    \@hangfrom{\hskip #2#3}{\ifstr{#1}{section}{\MakeTextLowercase{#4}}{#4}}%
}
\makeatother


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{tocstyle}
\newtocstyle
[KOMAlike]% parent style
[entryvskip]% exclude the initial vertical skip
{myown}% name of the new style
{\settocstylefeature[-1]{entryvskip}{12pt}}% set the vertical skip before a part entry
\usetocstyle{myown}

\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

\areaset[current]{336pt}{747pt}% 609 + 33 + 42 head \the\footskip
\setlength{\marginparwidth}{7.5em}%
\setlength{\marginparsep}{2em}



%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%5
\renewcommand*{\chapterheadendvskip}{%  
    \vspace{-.5\baselineskip}%
}
\begin{document}
    \microtypesetup{protrusion=false}
    \tableofcontents
    \listoffigures
    \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\vspace{.25\baselineskip}}%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%!!!
    \listoftables
%   \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\vspace{.25\baselineskip}}
    %\lstlistoflistings
    \cleardoubleoddpage
    \microtypesetup{protrusion=true}
    \part{Stuff}
    \blinddocument
    \part{More Stuff}
    \blinddocument
    \blinddocument
    \microtypesetup{protrusion=false}
    \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\vspace{12pt}}%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%!!!
    \printbibliography
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography} 
    \microtypesetup{protrusion=true}
    \part{Additional Stuff}
    \appendix
    \chapter{Even More Stuff}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update**

With the current [KOMA-Script Version 3.20](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/koma-script) new styles for toc entries can be easily declared. So you can define an own style for unnumbered chapters with more vertical space before.

```
\documentclass[
final,
paper=a4,
listof=totoc,
bibliography=totoc,
captions=tableheading,
numbers=noenddot,
headings=big,
chapterprefix=false
]
{scrreprt}[2016/05/10]% needs version 3.20 or newer
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex} 
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}% example bibdatei 

\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  tocbeforeskip=1.25em plus 1pt
]{part}
\addtokomafont{partentry}{\color{red!70!black}}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  tocbeforeskip=0pt plus .2pt,
]{chapter}
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[
  beforeskip=.75em plus 1pt,
  level=0,
  indent=0pt,
  numwidth=0pt,
]{chapter}{unnumberedchapter}

\renewcommand\addchaptertocentry[2]{%
  \ifstr{#1}{}
    {\addtocentrydefault{unnumberedchapter}{#1}{#2}}
    {\addtocentrydefault{chapter}{#1}{#2}}
}

%\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\cleardoubleoddpage
\part{Stuff}
\blinddocument
\part{More Stuff}
\blinddocument
\blinddocument
\nocite{westfahl:space}% nur für Beispielbibliography
\printbibliography
\addpart{Additional Stuff}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

**Original answer**

Here is a suggestion using package `tocstyle` that is an alpha version but part of the KOMA-Script bundle. It works also with `\addpart`.

```
    \documentclass[
    final,
    paper=a4,
    listof=totoc,
    captions=tableheading,
    listof=totoc,
    numbers=noenddot,
    headings=big,
    chapterprefix=false
    ]
    {scrreprt}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{blindtext}
    \usepackage{xcolor}% <- load this package before tocstyle
    \usepackage{tocstyle}
    \newtocstyle
         [KOMAlike]% parent style
         [entryvskip]% exclude the initial vertical skip
         {myown}% name of the new style
         {%
           \settocstylefeature[-1]{entryvskip}{12pt}% set the vertical skip before a part entry
           %\settocstylefeature[0]{entryvskip}{2pt}% set the vertical skip before a chapter entry
         }

    \usetocstyle{myown}
    \usepackage{hyperref}
    \begin{document}
             \tableofcontents
             \listoffigures
             \listoftables
             \cleardoubleoddpage
             \part{Stuff}
             \blinddocument
             \part{More Stuff}
             \blinddocument
             \blinddocument
             \addpart{Additional Stuff}
    \end{document}
```

Run several times to get

[image]

Another possibility is  redefining `\addparttocentry` and `\addchaptertocentry` but then there could be page breaks at unfavorable points.

```
    \documentclass[
    final,
    paper=a4,
    listof=totoc,
    captions=tableheading,
    listof=totoc,
    numbers=noenddot,
    headings=big,
    chapterprefix=false
    ]
    {scrreprt}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{blindtext}
    \usepackage{xcolor}
    \usepackage{hyperref}
    \renewcommand\addparttocentry[2]{%
        \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\vspace{-4ex}}%
        \addtocentrydefault{part}{#1}{#2}%
    }
  \renewcommand\addchaptertocentry[2]{%
        \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\vspace{-2ex}}%
        \addtocentrydefault{chapter}{#1}{#2}%
    }   
    \begin{document}
             \tableofcontents
             \listoffigures
             \listoftables
             \cleardoubleoddpage
             \part{Stuff}
             \blinddocument
             \part{More Stuff}
             \blinddocument
             \blinddocument
             \addpart{Additional Stuff}
    \end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks you very much for your solution. in your solution the space between the `list of's` and the bibliography is pretty small -- so I added same space with `\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\vspace{.25\baselineskip}}`. Do you know a more elegant way to achieve this? (I extended my example in the question)

Comment: LOF, LOT and the bibliography are at chapter level. So the vertical skip before them have the same value as before chapters. If there should be a small vertical skip before *every* chapter entry in the TOC you can uncomment the line `\settocstylefeature[0]{entryvskip}{2pt}% set the vertical skip before a chapter entry` in my first example. (I have just added this line.)

Comment: @harryhaller With the new version 3.20 it is possible. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to do it (version 2 would decrease inter-part space as well):

```
\documentclass[
final,
paper=a4,
captions=tableheading,
listof=totoc,
numbers=noenddot,
headings=big,
chapterprefix=false]
{scrreprt}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\let\origpart\part
\renewcommand{\part}[1]{\origpart{#1}\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\vspace{-2ex}}}% comment this line in version 2
%\renewcommand{\part}[1]{\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\vspace{-\baselineskip}}\origpart{#1}\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\vspace{-2ex}}}% uncomment this line in version 2

\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \listoffigures
    \listoftables
    \cleardoubleoddpage
    \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\vspace{-\baselineskip}}% comment this line in version 2
    \part{Stuff}
    \blinddocument  
    \part{More Stuff}
    \blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Comment: Note that this breaks `\addpart` and `\part*`.